# Initiating Phone Call with a button gives issues when view controller is embedded with Navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have a View controller with a button that initiates phone call and it works fine. But when i embed this view controller with a Navigation Controller it gives me this error in console " Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful."

I don't understand why i get this error because i haven't added any constraints yet. Can someone help?

Comment: (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14de2f3f0 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x14dd6d010]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x14dd39560 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14de29a20 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x14dd6d010]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x14dd39560 )>"
)

Comment: try clear all the contraint with clear all constraint and see if it works?

Comment: I don't have any constraints set. Why does the navigation controller interrupt the phone calling button? I'm breaking  my head with this.

Comment: I tried it and still getting the issue.